# _OBJC_CLASS $_ClasConfig reference from

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
/*
@protocol ClasConfig
@end
*/

//class A
@interface ClassA : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic) *companyA;
    @property (nonatomic) NSArray *companyLists;

     - (NSMutableArray*)getCompanyLists:(CompanyListModel *)productionListModel;
@end

 //class config
@interface ClasConfig : NSObject

    @property (nonatomic) NSString *Number;
    @property (nonatomic) NSString *totalNumberOfCompany;
@end


@implementation ClassA
 - (NSMutableArray*)getCompanyLists:(CompanyListModel *)productionListModel
{
 ClasConfig *config = [[ClasConfig alloc] init];  **//Gives me linker error**
}
@end
```

ClasConfig *config = [[ClasConfig alloc] init];  **//Gives me linker error**
Though I have tried with importing protocol for reference.

Comment: I think you missed `@implementation ClasConfig @end`.

Comment: @KudoCC Thanks. I have already answered. Yes I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

For got to implement class of ClassConfig.

```
@implementation ClassConfig
@end

@implementation ClassA
 - (NSMutableArray*)getCompanyLists:(CompanyListModel *)productionListModel
{
 ClasConfig *config = [[ClasConfig alloc] init];  **//Gives me linker error**
}
@end
```